# C: `Turn on debug messages

Tags: c, debugging, message

This is probably a really stupid question, but how do I turn on these debug messages in my code?

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MSG
    printf("initial state : %d\n", initial_state);
#endif
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to #define `DEBUG_MSG`. What's your compiler?

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Well, there _are,_ but this isn't one of them :-)

Comment: In case of ICC you also have to mention the operating system. By default, ICC emulates MSVC command lines options on windows, gcc's on unixlikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#ifdef` means 'If defined', your code essentially tells the preprocessor to check if `DEBUG_MSG` is defined somewhere else. If it is, it will include the code you've shown.

Comment: Yeah, all I had to do was set `#define DEBUG_MSG 1`... You can tell I'm a C noob

Comment: Actually you can leave out the `1`, all you need is for the macro to be defined. The expansion itself does not matter at all.

Answer (score 9):

When compiling, try something like this:

```
$ gcc -DDEBUG_MSG -o foo foo.c
```

Comment: +1, as this implies not having to modify the code itself to add the `#define`.

Answer (score 9):

You would have to `#define` that somehow.

***0. In your code.***

Directly in your code somewhere before you use that flag:

```
#define DEBUG_MSG
```

***1. On the command line.***

For each sourcefile, or appropriately in your makefile:

```
gcc -DDEBUG_MSG main.c
```

(For gcc, the flag is `-D<macro-name>`, for MSVC, it is `/D`, for ICC it is one of the former, depending on your operating system. )

***2. In your IDE, somewhere.***

In your IDE's project settings, find where you can put definitions. Under the hood, this is done using 1.

Comment: I so wanted to up vote this answer but the question is tagged [c] and you have used `g++`.

Comment: What the hell, it's the most complete answer here so I've corrected the compiler and up voted.

Comment: @JeremyP: Found another one: "main._cpp_"

Answer (score 2):

The C preprocessor phase will only pass code inside an `#ifdef/#endif` to the compiler phase if the symbol is defined.

You can generally do this in (at least) two ways.

The first is to use a command line switch for the compiler such as:

```
gcc -DDEBUG_MSG myprog.c
```

(`-D` means to define the pre-processor symbol following it and, although this is implementation-specific, many compilers use the same switch). The second is to place a line like:

```
#define DEBUG_MSG
```

inside your actual source code somewhere before the `#ifdef`.

The former is usually preferred since it allows you to control that behaviour without having to make changes to your source code so that, for example, you can have a debug and release build generated from the same source code.

Answer (score 1):

`#ifdef` will make your macro to be expanded only if `DEBUG_MSG` is defined. You can do this in two ways. Either do a `#define DEBUG_MSG 1` in your source or compile using `-DDEBUG_MSG` (if using `gcc`, there are similar flags for other compilers too)